# Using < > in text for asp:DropDownList option

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following in my .aspx file:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="title" Width="350px" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Dr">Dr</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Mr">Mr</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Ms">Ms</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Miss">Miss</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Mrs">Mrs</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like to put < > around "Please Select":

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0"><Please Select></asp:ListItem>
```

However, the file thinks I am opening a new tag when I use them.

Any ideas on how I can use these, possibly escaping them etc.,?

Comment: Is the `>` after `&gt;` deliberate or a typo in your reproduction?

Comment: Typo fixed example, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `Text` attribute you can use for the text instead of putting the text between the opening and closing tags:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="<Please Select>" />
```

You can also use the HTML entities if you prefer:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Please Select&gt;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` function

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

msdn link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/w3te6wfz.aspx